# Сервер MS SQL не найден или недоступен

Tags: sql-server

Не найдет сервер SQL сервер. 
[image: Здесь пусто]

Как мне найти этого, много чего попробовал не получится.

Comment: А в службах **SQL** **Server** запущен? Нужно создать эеземпляр сервера-службы. Тогда он станет тут доступен. Есть ещё случаи криво стал. У меня на win-7x64, сервер 2005 установился но криво, и не даёт создать службу пишет что с OS не совместим.

Comment: Да SQL Server запущен, с службой проблем нету. У меня win 10 x64. Sql 2016,

Comment: Основные упущения при инсталляции нового сервера:
1.Установить\обновить .NET Framework 
2.Включить TCP/IP в SQL Server Configuration Manager находится в    меню Start -> All Programs -> MS SQL Server -> Configuration Tools.TCP    Port 1433
3.В дереве элементов выбрать SQL Server Services. Убедиться, что SQL      Server Browser запущен.
4. Разрешить входящие соединения в Брандмауэре Windows на  TCP     Port 1433
5. В свойствах экземпляра, на странице подключений (Connections), убедиться, что стоит флажок у «Allow remote connections to this server»:

Comment: Посмотри если запущен SQL Browser он отвечает за то что-б служба SQL Server могла светиться.

Comment: 1. Подключаетесь ssms с того же компьютера, где установлен и запущен сервер? (если с другого - то дополнительный вопрос про то, есть ли связь по сети между машинами, не блокируется ли порт 1433, есть ли tcp ip или только named pipes) 2. Запущена ли служба SQL Browser (без неё можно подключиться к серверу напрямую, без этого окошка, но нужно знать точно параметры подключения. А вот "светится" в этом окошке именно из-за включенной службы Browser) В общем, уточняйте вопрос.